# Sort and print a list of 2 elemnts without saving the sorted version in another list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of 2 elements, a `string` and a `float` and I am trying to sort it in regards of the float elements to be in decending order, then print the top 5 elements of the list but I dont want to do this while saving the sorted list in another list.

I am having a little trouble with the last line of code.

I want to use the `descending` function of lists.

Here is my code:

```
List list = new List<Tuple<string, float>>();

for(i=100; i==0; i--)
{
   list.Add(new Tuple<string, float>("randomtext", i);
}

Console.WriteLine((from s in list orderby s.Item2 descending select s).Take(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Tuple<T1, T2>` and it has properties like `Item1` and `Item2` and thus you can do like

```
(from s in list         // Here each s is Tuple<string, float>
  orderby s.Item2 descending 
  select s).Take(5);
```

Well, per your post if you don't want this list to be stored and want to print the selected result then you can use `Foreach()` method

```
list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).Take(5).ToList()
.Foreach(data =>
{
 Console.WriteLine(data.Item1 + "\t" + data.Item2);
});
```

Your posted code is filled with compilation error as well your loop iteration logic `i == 0` is wrong as it will always return `false`. Have modified it as below.

```
  public static void Main()
  {
    List<Tuple<string, float>> list = new List<Tuple<string, float>>();

    for(int i=100; i > 0; i--)
    {
       list.Add(new Tuple<string, float>("randomtext", i));
    }

    list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).Take(5).ToList()
    .ForEach(data =>
    {
     Console.WriteLine(data.Item1 + "\t" + data.Item2);
    });
 }
```

Comment: @bary see edit in answer if that's what you intended

Comment: Your code throws me this error.               'List<Tuple<string, float>>' does not contain a definition for 'Foreach' and no accessible extension method 'Foreach' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Tuple<string, float>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @bary It's for you to debug/investigate and fix. Anyway see edit if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bubble Sort`

If you have a `List list = new List<Tuple<string, float>>();` you can use this code:

```
     float tempNum;
     string tempStr;

     for (int j = 0; j <= arr.Length - 2; j++) 
     {
        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length - 2; i++) 
        {
           if (arr[i][1] > list[i + 1][1]) //arr[i][1] is the float
           { 
              tempNum= arr[i + 1][1];
              tempStr= arr[i + 1][0];
              list[i + 1][0] = list[i][0];
              list[i + 1][1] = list[i][1];
              list[i][0] = tempStr;
              list[i][1] = tempNum;
           }
        }
     }
```

For more information link [HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Bubble-Sort-program-in-Chash)

Comment: I just edited the question to make the question more directed to find the descending method

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(List.Sort()[i])
}
```

Am I missing something?